# tabs inside StickyListHeadersListView's header in android

Tags: android

i have problem with putting tabs inside header of stickyList. I want three tabs and I put three textViews in header(as tabs) and change content of the list with clicking on these textViews but it's not working. my basic problem is how to handle the getView inside my adapter. I put switch/case inside getView but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FloatingGroupExpandableListView](https://github.com/diegocarloslima/FloatingGroupExpandableListView), Make the groups  expanded. To work around this library is much easier.